# "Unable to create component" error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a custom PDF viewer using [PDFLibNet](http://pdfviewer-win32.googlecode.com) library.
I downloaded compiled dlls (32 and 64 bit) and took a look to examples: very nice.
Then I started a library project in VS2010 and created a new user control (the one I want to export): dll compiled succesfully.
So I created a GUI project (net 4.0), referenced my assembly and dropped my control to main form: I have an error that says (I'm translating, so it could be wrong) *"Unable to create component 'PdfViewer'. Error message: 'System.IO:FileNotFoundException: unable to load file or assembly 'PDFLibNet, Version 1.0.6.8, .... or one of its dependencies. Unable to find specified file."*.
[image]
To prevent some question:

- Yes, my custom assembly references exactly that assembly
- Yes, PDFLibNet assembly is exactly 1.0.6.8
- In my control I tell to copy that DLL everytime
- I tried to add PDFLibNet reference to GUI project, but I had the same error

Here is what I left after deleting everything (for testing purpose):

```
public partial class PdfViewer : UserControl
{
    PDFWrapper _pdfDoc = null;

    public PdfViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Just to tell you: if I try to remove any reference to PDFLibNet (removing `PDFWrapper _pdfDoc = null;`), my control is dropped correctly on form.
I even tried to register PDFLibNet into GAC, but the result is the same.
I'm really confused...

Comment: try to add reference to PDFLibNet in your GUI project.

Comment: make sure you don't check debug folder and the output mode is release.

Comment: @Miroprocessor: post your comment as answer, because it worked and I want to thank you. But can you tell me the reason of this? Why in Release mode it works and in debug mode no?

Comment: @Miroprocessor: How can I let it work in even in Debug mode? Is it possible in your opinion?

Comment: in case of debug mode, the .net looking for required dlls in bin/debug folder but the output mode is release and these ddls will be copied to bin/release folder.so you have to copy ddls into bin/debug folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you don't check debug folder and the output mode is release.